# Why my list's values does not change in some part of my code?

Tags: python, list, pass-by-reference

I was doing some Hackerrank exercises, and came across this problem about swapping elements. My question is about lists in general, why does the elements in "arr" does not change in the second for loop as it does in the first for loop?

```
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    arr = [i-1 for i in arr]
    ls = []

    minimumSwaps = 0
    for i, j in enumerate(arr):
        print(arr)
        if j == arr[j]:
            continue
        else:
            test = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[j]
            arr[j] = test
            minimumSwaps += 1
            ls.append(arr[i])
    print('\n\n')
    for i in range(len(ls)):
        print(arr)
        if i == arr[i]:
            continue
        else:
            test = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[arr[i]]
            arr[arr[i]] = test
            minimumSwaps +=1


    return minimumSwaps

minimumSwaps([4,3,1,2])
```

The output of the first loop is:

[3, 2, 0, 1]

[1, 2, 0, 3]

[1, 0, 2, 3]

[1, 0, 2, 3]

which is what I expected, but the second loop output gives me this:

[1, 0, 2, 3]

[1, 0, 2, 3]  <---  if it had the same behavior as the first loop, it would be [0, 1, 2, 3]

Comment: Why are you printing *before* you do anything to the list, instead of after?

Comment: @user2357112 It was just for testing purposes, it does not affect in any way. After the first iteration of the second for loop, it should have changed the list anyways, but it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

On the `i==0` iteration, `test = arr[i]` assigns 1 to `test`.

`arr[i] = arr[arr[i]]` assigns 0 to `arr[0]`.

`arr[arr[i]] = test` assigns 1 *back to `arr[0]`*, not `arr[1]`, because `arr[0]` is 0 at this point, not 1.

End result: nothing has changed.